What PrivateUsers= does exactly?
I am having a hard time understanding Manual for PrivateUsers=. It mentions a few caveats for it to fail silently... But I think i'm avoiding them all and still not managing to reach the manual promise of "and thus to create an effective sandbox environment."

If true, sets up a new user namespace for the executed processes and configures a minimal user and group mapping, that maps the "root" user and group as well as the unit's own user and group to themselves and everything else to the "nobody" user and group.

To me, it's not clear what the manual means by "the unit's own user and group". Is it User=? I don't think so because that would make starting the process as root mapped to a local user impossible (i would have to use User=root to start the process as the namespaced root, but that would also make root the user that root maps to...). The term "own user" is never mentioned in any of the many manual pages required to understand a service unit file, only three times in the paragraph for PrivateUsers=.
I set up this very simple test service
[Unit]                                                                                                                                                                    
Description=My test
[Service]
Type=simple
PrivateUsers=yes
User=http
ExecStart=...

That is exactly the same as
[Unit]                                                                                                                                                                    
Description=My test
[Service]
Type=simple
User=http
ExecStart=...

(without privateusers)
I cannot tell any difference between these two in my tests. Both access all local users with no mapping taking place.

All files, directories, processes, IPC objects and other resources owned by users/groups not equaling "root" or the unit's own will stay visible from within the unit but appear owned by the "nobody" user and group.

I see and create everything owned by the regular users inside and out of the scope.

If this mode is enabled, all unit processes are run without privileges in the host user namespace (regardless if the unit's own user/group is "root" or not).

Again, not sure what it means by unit's own user. Am I expected to assume ui 0 after starting the process as another User=?

Note that the implementation of this setting might be impossible (for example if user namespaces are not available), and the unit should be written in a way that does not solely rely on this setting for security.

Running unshare -U on the host works fine and creating files as root shows as a different user, as expected.

oh! ...is "own user" meaning that it must be a "user service" not a system one?! is this 'rootless' nonsense?

"I don't think so because that would make starting the process as root mapped to a local user impossible" ... Having looked at the linked doc, nowhere does it imply such a thing is intended. Why do you need it for an effective sandbox?

@muru at this point i am at a total loss. I cannot get a usernamespace with systemd at all.

@muru and answering your question "Why do you need it for an effective sandbox", to have effective sandbox one does need user namespace, otherwise root in the container is root outside of the container. To sandbox it to the limits of one user, root in the container should be at most that user outside of the container.

@gdb no, I mean why do you need any process to be root in the sandbox? And even if some process were running as root, as the manual states, it doesn't gain any privileges inside it.

@muru it might expect root for things like nginx which open low ports and then fork. "as the manual states" well, that is assuming the user namespace sandbox is working, which in my tests it clearly isn't. Any exploit in the container code will have root access on the host too.

Ah, but you don't need to be root anymore. You use systemd sockets instead to have systemd do the work of setting up ports and hand it over to the corresponding service. Even if you didn't want to use sockets for some reason, you could just assign the required capability to the service instead of running the whole thing as root. I can't comment about your tests because you haven't actually shown any tests.

@muru there's a 4yr thread on nginx to move to that pattern :) meanwhile, the tests are the two service files, one using PrivateUsers=, the other do not. Both create a process for the exec line without user namespace.

They might not have changed the default service files from nginx, but you can't still go the capabilities way without having to wait for them to do anything. Yes, I see those service files, but what were the tests? What did you run, what did you get, what did you expect and what part of the documentation makes you think that this isn't expected?

And also, of course, other details such as which version of systemd, which OS (hopefully kernel version as well), whether user namespaces are enabled in your kernel, etc., etc
